# How to change SKU in live app in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app is live in the App Store now. But I want to change some SKU in this app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [iTunes Connection Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) section of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH1-SW1):

> SKU Number
>
> A unique ID for your app in the Apple system that is not seen by users. You can use letters, numbers, hyphens, periods, and underscores. The SKU can’t start with a hyphen, period, or underscore.
>   Use a value that is meaningful to your organization.
>
> Can’t be edited after saving the iTunes Connect record.

You can't change the SKU. You are stuck with whatever you originally entered.